# Suggestions of users to follow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on social media site, but I can't get a logic that how do I give a list of suggested users to follow.

Users table :-

```
id  |  name  |  username  |  password
```

Relationship table :-

```
id  |  followee  |  follower
```

where followee and follower are the foreign keys to users table.
I tried some sql joins and also put some logic in backend but that didn't worked.
Here is what I tried :-

```
select u.id, u.name from users u, relationship r on u.id = r.follower where u.id != (user_id) and r.follower != (user_id)
```

Here in user_id I have to pass the id of the logged in user, so that I want to return the list of users whom current user don't follow and if relationship table is empty then it must return all the users from users table except current user.

Here I also want to return distinct values from users table and follower column.

Here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1pNr.png) I have provided an image of sample data.
If current user id 187 follows all users then it must return empty data.

if current user id 188 doesn't follow anybody then it must return data of 187 and 198.

Comment: Please provide sample data for the two tables and the required query result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [NOT IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
  SELECT r.followee FROM relationship
  WHERE r.follower = (user_id) 
) AND u.id != (user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked, but this query is for users whom current user don't follow. Then how can I suggest a list of users to whom he must follow.

Comment: @siddharth that is business logic and should be coded in the backend; there is no such simple query to do this